# How do I know I'm using kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu

I installed Kubuntu image long time ago, and did several release upgrades since that. I have package `kubuntu-full` installed, and boot into KDE. Currently it looks like I'm using ubuntu:

```
~: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:        13.10
Codename:       saucy
```

There's not a single kubuntu word in my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or is it

```
Kubuntu = Ubuntu - Unity + KDE
```

now?

For example there's a Pre-Alpha Ubuntu Thar already, but no Kubuntu one. Would I get Kubuntu Thar, by installing Ubuntu Thar in the way mentioned above?

Probably Kubuntu team now are the guys responsible for KDE working in Ubuntu.

Comment: Just Post a Picture Also check the unity interface and compare it

Comment: I know I'm using KDE. The question is about the current status of kubuntu and its relation to ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Recognised Ubuntu flavours**

The list of recognised Ubuntu flavours: http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives

**Kubuntu**

Kubuntu = Ubuntu core packages + KDE desktop + Kubuntu default settings

You could have the KDE desktop without the Kubuntu.

Older kubuntu-default-settings : http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kubuntu-default-settings&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Current kubuntu-settings-desktop: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kubuntu-settings-desktop&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

**Kubuntu default settings**

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/kubuntu-settings-desktop :

> Settings and artwork for the Kubuntu

If the Kubuntu default setting is installed:

- The Grub is telling that you have an option to launch the Kubuntu
- The Plymouth is telling that the Kubuntu is starting
- The KDE default application launcher has the Kubuntu logo
- The desktop cube has the Kubuntu logo
- The default plasma desktop is having the Kubuntu default settings
- etc...

The KDE System Settings > About System is telling that you are using the Kubuntu

[image]

**Trusty**

The Kubuntu daily builds are still pointing to the Saucy: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/daily-live/current/

The Kubuntu Trusty can be installed by installing the Kubuntu Saucy and upgrading to the Trusty.

The Trusty development is still fresh  - Kubuntu plans can be found from the Kubuntu Trello: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?63870-When-is-the-new-LTS-due&p=337565&viewfull=1#post337565

Answer (score 0):

I'm using gnomeubuntu and this is what shows up it terminal when typing: lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
```

so I'm guessing this is a normal thing with other ubuntu distributions.

Answer (score 0):

Kubuntu is Ubuntu.

It just uses KDE (including KDE-specific programs) instead of Unity/GNOME.

Edit: Maybe `cat /etc/issue.net` works. I'm using Ubuntu so I can't check it.

Comment: `issue.net` gives me `Ubuntu Trusty Tahr (development branch)` (I've upgraded meanwhile).

Comment: Hm... so it doesn't work.

Comment: nope. that does not work. I get that kubuntu is nothing technical, all that interests me is for a script to be able to detect KDE environement.